# How to retrieve the contents of a particular Array, the name of which is in a variable, in Swift 2

Tags: arrays, string, swift

I want to be able to print the contents of the array Tom001 using the string c or d. How do I do that?

```
var tom001 = [1,2,3]

var c = "tom"
c += "001"

var d = "\(c)"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: Converting a string into a variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321778/swift-converting-a-string-into-a-variable-name)

Comment: You cant. Swift is a type safe language. You cannot create dynamic variable/array names  like php.

Comment: Only if you are willing to dive deep into the ObjC Runtime Library. And even then, there are limitations to what can be done.