# Swift, use string name to reference a variable

Tags: string, swift, variables, dictionary

Plan to use a string value to for referencing which variable I want to update.  Combining string from a few different user selected sources.  To many possibilities to use if/case statements.  Thanks in advance

```
var d1000: Int = 0
// ...
var d1289: Int = 0
// ...
var d1999: Int = 0

var deviceIDtype: Character = "d" // button press assigns some value, d used for example
var deviceIDsection: String = "12" // button press assigns some value, 12 used for example
var deviceID: String = "89" // button press assigns some value, 89 used for example

var ref:String = ""

func devName(dIDt:Character, dIDs: String, dID: String)  -> String {      
    var combine: String = String(dIDt) + (dIDs) + (dID)
    return (combine) 
}

ref = devName(deviceIDtype, dIDs: deviceIDsection, dID: deviceID) // ref equals d1289 in this example


// d1289 = 1234 // trying to set this using the ref variable value, failed attempts below
/(ref) = 1234 // set d1289 variable to equal "1234"
"/(ref)" = 1234 // set d1289 variable to equal "1234"
get(ref) = 1234 // set d1289 variable to equal "1234"
get.ref = 1234 // set d1289 variable to equal "1234"
```

Comment: You probably can use `Mirror` (https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Mirror_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structctr/Mirror/s:FVs6MirrorcFT10reflectingP__S_).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using a dictionary, `[String : Int]`?

This will allow you to achieve what you want - storing values for different keys.

For example, instead of using

```
var d1000 = 0
var d1289 = 0
var d1999 = 0
```

You could use

```
var dictionary: [String : Int] = [
  "d1000" : 0,
  "d1289" : 0,
  "d1999" : 0
]
```

To store a value in the dictionary, just use

```
dictionary[key] = value
//for example, setting "d1289" to 1234
dictionary["d1289"] = 1234
```

and to get the value from the dictionary, use

```
let value = dictionary[key]
//for example, getting the value of "d1289"
let value = dictionary["d1289"]
```

So, you could use something like this

```
//initialize your dictionary
var myDictionary: [String : Int] = [:]

//your key initialization data
var deviceIDtype: Character = "d"
var deviceIDsection: String = "12"
var deviceID: String = "89"
var ref: String = ""

//your code
func devName(/*...*/){/*...*/}
ref = devName(/*...*/)

//set the key ref (fetched from devName) to 1234
myDictionary[ref] = 1234
```

Just as a side note, you could really clean some of your code

```
func devName(type: Character, section: String, id: String) -> String{      
    return String(type) + section + id
}

//...

let key = devName(deviceIDtype, section: deviceIDsection, id: deviceID)
let value = 1234
myDictionary[key] = value
```

Answer (score 8):

It is possible!!!

```
let index = 1000
if let d1000 = self.value(forKey: "d\(index)") as? Int {
    // enjoy
}
```

Comment: How can the result be an Int?, it's got a "d" (string), in the key's value, so can't be an integer, right?

Comment: d1000 is the key. i,e. the variable name. Int is the value it contains. it depends on how you declare d1000 in your class(self). check out this example. `class Temp { var myVar = "hello"}` in this case if i take `value(forKey:)`, i will get String. `if let myVarRep = self.value(forKey: "myVar") as? String {}`