# Convert Swift variable name to string, to use as string?

Tags: swift, string, variables, converters

I've got a texture to import that's named the same as the variable boolean that represents its state.

```
let myButtonNameABC = false
```

is there a way to convert the name of this variable to a String so it can be used to load the images that are named the same?

Comment: I think your answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005654/swift-get-variable-actual-name-as-string)

Comment: @RayToal it seems this it it... `NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", #keyPath(Person.firstName), "Andrew")` but where is the variable name in this example, and where is it sent and stored?

Comment: I don't actually know for sure, since I only write pure Swift with no Objective-C interop. If you can interop with keyPath then great, and maybe someone else will answer here. But I wonder if the better answer is to not do this kind of thing in Swift. Rather than making a variable whose actual name you care about, consider a Dictionary where you have much easier access to key names without polluting the code with Objective-C? (Just a thought...)

Comment: This would make for an interesting proposal.  If you have anything you'd like to share, please start a discussion on swift-evolution requesting this feature.

Comment: Answer for your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45622489/1465582

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make this a function instead of a variable, and do the same thing. I'll explain it in steps.

So first, how do we make a function the same thing as a variable?

Basically, we are "wrapping" the variable inside of the function. This is a similar to approach to the first block I suggested in your latest RefBool thread, where we grabbed or set a value via function.

Here, we are using methods/functions to alter a variable directly without parameters--so, we will be using the function by name instead of using the variable by name to access it throughout our code:

```
enum Static {
  private static var _button1 = false
  static func button1() { toggle(&_button1) }
}
```

Note, *the Enum is just a namespace for us to call the method to emphasize that the variable's name is not needed for our code to work*--Only the function needs to know its name.This code would work inside of a struct or class as well, or even in a global namespace.

**So here, if I want to change the value of `_button1`, I must call `button1()`.**  `_button1` is essentially invisible to everyone and everything--and that's ok, because we only need `button1()` to do our work.

So now, every time we call `Static.button1()` , `Static._button1` will toggle `true` to `false`, `false` to `true`, and so on (using the function I gave you earlier)

---

*Why are we doing this?*

Well, because there is no way to get the name of a variable without `Mirror` and reflection, and there is already a built-in command called `#function`. We are jumping through the added hoop of using the function, so we don't have to set-up a mirror and other OBJc hoops.

Let's alter our `enum` to demonstrate how we can get the name of the `func`:

```
 enum Static {
  private static var _button1 = false
  
  static func button1() -> String { 
    toggle ( &_button1 ) 
    return ( #function )
  }
}
```

---

Now, when we call `button1()`, we do two things: 1, we toggle the state of the button (_button1), and we return a string with the name "button1()"

```
let buttonName = Static.button1()  // buttonName = "button1()"
```

We can make this more usable by calling a member of `String` to mutate itself:

```
let trimmedButtonName = Static.button1().replacingOccurrences(of: "()", with: "")
// trimmedButtonName = "button1"
```

---

Let's update our `enum` now with this handy replacement:

```
enum Static {
  private static var _button1 = false
  
  static func button1() -> String { 
    toggle ( &_button1 ) 
    return ( #function.replacingOccurrences(of: "()", with: "") )
  }
}
```

And our final use case is as follows:

```
let buttonName = Static.button1()
```

---

#### Note:

You don't have to have `_button1` as private, that was just to demonstrate that you don't *need* it to be public. If you need to grab the state of it, you can make another function, or return a tuple type from `button1()`:

```
static func button1() -> (name: String, state: Bool) {
// ...        
  return ( #function.etc, _button1)
}

let results = Static.button1()
print( results.name  ) // "button1"
print( results.state ) //  true / false
```

You can also set something in the parameter if you need more explicit control over setting the variable, just as you would any normal function.

---

**UPDATE:**

For example, if you wanted to use explicit control, you could do:

```
func button1(equals: Bool? = nil) -> (name: String, state: Bool) {
  if equals != nil {
    // do the code mentioned above
  } else {
    _button1 = equals!
  }

  return (#function.replacingOccurrences(of: "()", with: ""), _button1)
}

let buttonState.state = Static.button1(equals: false) // false
let buttonStateAgain.state = Static.button1(equals: true) // true
print(Static.button1().name) // "button1"
```

Comment: This still doesn't address local variables.  Plus it's a lot of boilerplate for something that should be... well, free.

Comment: @CodaFi please share your alternative

Comment: How about a [swift-evolution proposal](https://swift.org/contributing/)?

Comment: @CodaFi that's cool and all, but you are being critical of my workaround since it should be free--but it's not. I don't understand

Comment: I'm critical of this because it's legitimately a language limitation, and one that we are aware of.  Stringification of variables is something any half-decent preprocessor is capable off; something that can be implemented in the compiler trivially.  tl;dr Boilerplate is boilerplate, but this is something that merits a higher-level and more general solution.

Comment: @CodaFi so basically your criticism has nothing to do with my answer or my attempt to help the OP. I don't deserve my answers to be brought down for something inherently wrong with the language that I have no control over. 2c.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129077/discussion-between-codafi-and-fluidity).

Answer (score 3):

You can use Mirror for this.

```
struct Test {
    let myButtonNameABC = false
}

let childrens = Mirror(reflecting: Test()).children

childrens.forEach {
    print($0.label ?? "")
}
```

This will print:

```
myButtonNameABC
```

You can find for information about Mirror [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/mirror).

Comment: you would have to set up a lot of pattern matching to find just the variable you wanted though, wouldn't you? Or are you saying to make a new struct for each variable?