# How to put a variable in a for loop with different end number

Tags: swift, xcode, for-loop

I’ve got multiple variables with the same name but a different number on the end like this:

`MyVar1`, `MyVar2`, `MyVar3`, `MyVar4`
and they are either true or false

How do I write this correctly?

```
For index in Range(1...4){
    if (“MyVar” + index) == true{
       print(“:)”)
    }
}
```

Comment: We get what you are trying to achieve but the answers bellow are correct, eventhough it doesnt correctly answers your question. You are trying to increment the variable names, but you definitely should place them into an array. This pretty much suggests that your model (`MyVar1` `MyVar2` etc.. ) is not totally accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

didnt tries the solution but according to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45622489/5464805 you can do this:

*Edit: I read that your variables are Booleans*

```
for i in 0...4 {
   if let var = myObject.value(forKey: "MyVar\(i)") as Bool, 
      var { // If var is successfully cast and true it enters the statement
      print(var)
   }
}
```

**HOWEVER**

All the other solutions above or below are still correct. This is something you dont usually do in Swift in general unless you must do so.
You should either rewrite your model and give a proper name to each variables, that you will later put into an array such as...

```
class MyObject {
   var MyVar1: Bool // To Rename
   var MyVar2: Bool // To Rename
   var MyVar3: Bool // To Rename

   var MyVars: [Bool] { 
     get { return [MyVar1, MyVar2, MyVar3]  }
   }
}
```

Or you completely get rid of these variable and create an Array directly

```
class MyObject {
   // var MyVar1: Bool // To Delete
   // var MyVar2: Bool // To Delete
   // var MyVar3: Bool // To Delete

   var MyVars: [Bool]
}
```

and you set the Array / Dictionnary in accordance to your needs

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get a sum of `String` ("MyVar") and `Int` ("index") and compare that sum with `Bool` (true)

It would be more safety to store all your variables in an array like that

```
let myVars = [MyVar1, MyVar2, MyVar3, MyVar4]
```

Then you can iterate throught the array:

```
for i in myVars {
    if i {
        print(i)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a variable from concatenation at runtime , you need to have an array of bool like this

```
var arr = [false,true,true,false] // var1 , var2 , var3 , var4
for item in arr {
   if item {
   }
}
```