# swift / changing name of variable in loop

Tags: swift, loops, variables

How could i change name of variable in loop? 
like number1 , number2, number3, number4 ?

```
var array = [2,4,6,8]
func ap ( number1: Int , number2: Int , number3: Int , number4: Int ) {
    for (index,_) in array.enumerated() {
    array[index] += **("number\(index)")**
    }
        print(array)
}
ap(number1: 2, number2: 4, number3: 6, number4: 8)
```

Comment: You're looking for an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321778/swift-converting-a-string-into-a-variable-name) says not possible and to use an array instead.

Here is using another array:

```
var array = [2,4,6,8]

func ap ( number1: Int , number2: Int , number3: Int , number4: Int ) {

    let arrayOfParameters = [number1, number2, number3, number4]

    for (index,_) in array.enumerated() {
        array[index] += arrayOfParameters[index]
    }
    print(array)
}
ap(number1: 2, number2: 4, number3: 6, number4: 8)
```

prints: [4, 8, 12, 16]